# convert a base64 image string to a image file that can be served to browsers using node.js

Tags: image, node.js, cross-browser, png, base64

The issue was to do with the HTTP ACCEPT header not being accepted by Restify, the image rendering code is fine.

---

I have an image encoded as a base64 string, and I want to serve this as an image using node.js. Currently I've got the following code (I'm using Restify) which renders the image in Chrome OK, but the image doesn't render in other browsers (tried IE9, Firefox 4, Android browser):

```
var decodedBuffer = new Buffer(dataString,"base64");            
    res.send({
          code: 200,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Content-Length': decodedBuffer.length},   
          noEnd: true                               
    });     

    res.write(decodedBuffer);                       
    res.end();
```

Anyone able to shed some light on what I might be doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: what data you get from server? try to curl/wget image and open it in the image editor. Is it png?

Comment: @Andy Britcliffe if you find the solution, plz help us by let us know your solution. I faced the same prob as you... Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Use [data URI syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897), which means you have to prefix the response with the data protocol and the MIME type, plus specify base64 encoding:

```
res.write("data:image/png;base64,"+decodedBuffer);
```